# WHERE_IN returns only first match in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get a list of coupons through ajax when the checkboxes are selected. So everything else is working fine but the query is returning only the first match.

So my query is:

```
$this->db->from('tbl_coupons');
        if($storeids !=''){
         $ids = array($storeids);
$this->db->where_in('coupon_store', $ids );
        }       
        $this->db->where('coupon_cat', $catid);
        $this->db->where('coupon_status', 'active');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $ds = $query->result_array();}
```

According to this my SQLquery becomes

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_coupons` 
WHERE `coupon_store` IN('1,97') 
AND `coupon_cat` = '16' 
AND `coupon_status` = 'active'
```

But this query is returning values with `coupon_store=1` and no results are coming for `coupon_store=97`

I checked values for coupon store 97 which exists in that category.

Comment: Because query is incorrect .
Correct query is: `SELECT * FROM tbl_coupons WHERE coupon_store IN('1','97') AND coupon_cat = '16' AND coupon_status = 'active'` .
Look at IN('1', '97') quotes.
Check what data in `$ids` variable.

Comment: @mcklayin yup thanks it worked

Answer (score 2):

use below way if data exist it will be part of query.

```
        storeids = explode(',',storeids);
        $ids = array();
        foreach($storeids as $val){
            $ids[] = $val;
        }
        if(!empty($ids)){
            $this->db->where_in('coupon_store', $ids );
        }
```

hope it will create proper sql query

Answer (score 0):

The query is mostly correct, except at line 2, where you need to make the change as:

`WHERE coupon_store IN('1','97')`

everything else remains the same.